# creating a function that assigns multiple dataframe (additional question) in R

Tags: r, function

I have a for loop that assigns multiple data frames in different values and it works by itself. But when I try to create a function with this for loop, it doesn't work. On top of assigning different names to different data frames, I'm also trying to create a vector that keeps the names of these dataframes, but seems like this function doesn't save "dfnames"

```
create_df <- function(name){
dfnames <- c() 
  for(i in name){
     assign(paste0("subject", i, sep = "_"), passive_subject(i))
     dfnames <- c(dfnames, paste0("subject", i, sep = "_"))
     dfnames
     } 
}
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: What is `passive_subject`

Comment: Are you assign ing objects to global env

Comment: you should not use `assign` for something like this. Use a list instead. See dww's answer.

Comment: You are creating a mess. The various `subject_n` objects are not in a list and are separate from the collection of their names. It's not surprising that you are not getting what you want. You shoudl be creating a list with names, rather than a bunch of separate objects and a separate naming vector. You should change the checkmark to award @dww

Comment: Voting to close because it remains very unclear what was intended because the is no[MCVE] or even a good description of the data inputs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the function, there is  no `return` value.  We can add the `return` value and it works.

```
create_df <- function(name){
   dfnames <- c() 
   for(i in name){
     assign(paste0("subject", i, sep = "_"), passive_subject(i), 
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
     dfnames <- c(dfnames, paste0("subject", i, sep = "_"))
     
     } 
   return(dfnames)
}
```

Comment: is there a way to run dfnames anytime? because right now the names show when I run the whole function but I hope to run dfnames by itself sometimes

Comment: I didn't understand your question.  Inside the function, you are creating the dfnames as a `NULL` element `c()`

Comment: Returning the names vector did nothing to return the subject_n values.

Comment: @IRTFM Please look at OP's question - `but seems like this function doesn't save "dfnames"`.

Comment: I did look at his question. I’m guessing that ‘passive_subject’ is a data object rather than a function. Hi s strategy is all wrong in any case and he needs advice about how to avoid creating unwieldy data designs.

Comment: @IRTFM My solution works on the OP's current approach and the question was not about how to do this in a better way

Comment: This is an example from today's Q&A that shows the correct way (obviously in my opinion) to respond in such situations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198745/for-loop-with-dplyr

Comment: @IRTFM I agree that the code used is not the optimal one.  But,  many times, people work with codes just to understand the dynamics and not for actual purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It would almost certainly be better to return a list of the data frames, and set the names of that list. In general this is a tidier approach than having lots of similar data.frames as separate objects.

```
create_df <- function(name){
   l = lapply(name, passive_subject)
   names(l) = paste0("subject", name, sep = "_")
   return(l)
}
```